# button with options MaterialUI

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I use [MaterialUI](https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/)

I would like to put a button that has an arrow with some options

How to do it

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/) docs, you will find everything there. Below is a working example from the official docs, showing the button with drop down using popper for overlaying.

**Working Example:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/t3rjo?file=/demo.js:1930-1936